# A public server i can ping for a speed test application

Tags: performance, testing, server

I am researching before I create a internet speed application. I was wondering if anyone knows of a service in which I can ping, download and upload samples of various sizes to a server. The samples will not be saved, its just for speed testing. I tried looking this up but its not a very easy to search topic. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would use iperf or something like this for such purposes, some additional information can be found here https://askubuntu.com/a/7977